# updating values table using generic dictionary where statement

Tags: c#

I want to update the data in the database, but I want to use the condition Where
The following code works well for inserting data....
this code in class (DB_Access)

```
public static string CreateInsertSql(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap)
    {
        var keys = parameterMap.Keys.ToList();
        // ToList() LINQ extension method used because order is NOT
        // guaranteed with every implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
        var sql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO ").Append(table).Append("(");

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            sql.Append(keys[i]);
            if (i < keys.Count - 1)
                sql.Append(", ");
        }

        sql.Append(") VALUES(");

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            sql.Append('@').Append(keys[i]);
            if (i < keys.Count - 1)
                sql.Append(", ");
        }

        return sql.Append(")").ToString();
    }
    public void SqlInsert(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap)
    {
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

           {
             using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
               {
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    command.CommandText = CreateInsertSql(table, parameterMap);
                    foreach (var pair in parameterMap)
                    command.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
               }
            }
     }
```

Use the following code to implement (
DB_Access access = new DB_Access(); )

```
access.SqlInsert("`seal`", new Dictionary<string, string>()
                    {
                        { "s_name",txt_item.Text },
                        { "s_qty",txt_qty.Value.ToString() },
                        { "s_sn",txt_sn.Text },
                        { "s_moon",txt_moon.Text },
                        { "s_market",txt_market.Text },
                        { "s_date", txt_date.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") },
                        { "s_detiles",txt_det.Text },
                        { "s_pay",groupBox2.Text },

                    });
```

> > >
> >     but i used this code for update data .. but not work
> >     .... in class DB_Access

```
 public static string CreateEditSql(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap)
    {
        var keys = parameterMap.Keys.ToList();
        // ToList() LINQ extension method used because order is NOT
        // guaranteed with every implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue>

        var sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE ").Append(table).Append(" SET ");

        for (var i = 1; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            sql.Append(keys[i]).Append(" = @").Append(keys[i]);
            if (i < keys.Count - 1)
                sql.Append(", ");
        }

        return sql.Append(" WHERE ").Append(keys[0]).Append(" = @").Append(keys[0]).ToString();
    }

    public void SqlEdit(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap)
    {
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        {
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = CreateEditSql(table, parameterMap);
                foreach (var pair in parameterMap)
                    command.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

the message Error (An item with the same key has already been add)
....

> Query the problem depends on the employee's name not id .. and i need edit name ....... Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
public static string CreateEditSql(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap, string werename, string weretext)
    {
        var keys = parameterMap.Keys.ToList();
        // ToList() LINQ extension method used because order is NOT
        // guaranteed with every implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue>

        var sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE ").Append(table).Append(" SET ");

        for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
        {
            sql.Append(keys[i]).Append(" = @").Append(keys[i]);
            if (i < keys.Count - 1)
                sql.Append(", ");
        }

        return sql.Append(" WHERE ").Append("`").Append(werename).Append("`").Append(" = ").Append(weretext).ToString();
    }

    public void SqlEdit(string table, IDictionary<string, string> parameterMap,string werename , string weretext)
    {
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Closed")
        {
            conn.Open();
        }

        {
            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = conn;
                command.CommandText = CreateEditSql(table, parameterMap,werename,weretext);
                foreach (var pair in parameterMap)
                    command.Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
access.SqlEdit("`employee`", new Dictionary<string, string>() 
                {
                  //  { "e_name",txt_nameedit.Text },
                    { "e_name",txt_name.Text },
                  //  { "e_pic",ImageData.ToString() },
                   // { "e_datebegin",txt_bigdate.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") },
                    //{ "e_datebirth",txt_date.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") },
                    //{ "e_loc",txt_loc.Text },
                   // { "e_mony",txt_mony.Text },
                   // { "e_mob",txt_mob.Text },
                   // { "e_use",txt_user.Text },
                   // { "e_pass",txt_pass.Text },
                   // { "e_prv",txt_prv.Text },

                }, "e_name", txt_nameedit.Text);
```